# how to combine a viewmodel with various other fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my mvc4 application I need to create a view where customers can choose from a list of services, subscribe (by selecting the yes/no option) and give details of the last service date they had the service done and also provide a proposed date for the future service. It should roughly look like as below

. [image]

I have a services table in the database like Services(Id,Name etc) but don't know how shall I combine the other values which I m showing like `yes/no` and the two dates in a single viewModel and pass it to view and retrieve all the values on post back. In simple words which fields will my viewmodel have? Any ideas. thanks

Comment: You view model needs properties for each property of `Service` and additional properties for the boolean property and the 2 dates.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for the comment. What you are suggesting the view model may look like this `public class ServiceSubscriptionViewModel
    {
        public Service Service { get; set; }
        public bool Subscribed { get; set; }
        public DateTime ServiceDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProposedDate { get; set; }
    }` if so then how can we fill this ViewModel from services table from the database and pass to view?

Comment: Rather than `public Service service { get; set; }` the correct approach is to have a corresponding property for each property of `Service` that you want to display/edit. You just need to get the `Service` from the database, initialize a new instance of the view model, map the values from the data model to the view model, and pass the view model to the view. You can use tools such as [automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to make this easier.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for more than just a view model.  To expand on shenku's answer, this would be my rough/untested approach in VB.  It's no way all-inclusive, but hopefully gives you an idea on how to manipulate data, pass it to a view, and get data back on post-back.

Model/DB objects:

```
Public Class Service
    Public Property ServiceID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class

Public Class CustomerService
    Public Property CustomerID As Integer
    Public Property ServiceID As Integer
    Public Property Selected As Boolean
    Public Property LastDate As DateTime
    Public Property ProposedDate As DateTime
End Class
```

ViewModel:

```
Public Class ViewRow
    Public Property ServiceID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property YesSelected As Boolean
    Public Property NoSelected As Boolean
    Public Property LastDate As String
    Public Property ProposedDate As String
End Class

Public Class ViewModel
    Public Property TableHeaders As String() = {"Services","Yes","No","Date of Last Service", "Proposed Date"}
    Public Property ServiceDetails As List(Of ViewRow)
End Class
```

Controller:

```
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    ' Simulating EntityFramework
    Protected db As New MyEntities

    Function ServiceList() As ActionResult

        Dim thisCustomerID As Integer
        ' *Set user's customer ID*

        ' Using a LINQ join to combine with other service information
        Dim vm As New ViewModel With {
            .ServiceDetails = ( _
                From custService In db.CustomerService().ToList()
                Join service In db.Service().ToList()
                On custService.ServiceID Equals service.ServiceID
                Where custService.CustomerID.Equals(thisCustomerID)
                Select New ViewRow With {
                    .ServiceID = service.ServiceID,
                    .Name = service.Name,
                    .YesSelected = custService.Selected,
                    .NoSelected = Not custService.Selected,
                    .LastDate = custService.LastDate.ToString("MMM yyyy"),
                    .ProposedDate = custService.ProposedDate.ToString("MMM yyyy")                  
                }).ToList()
            }

        ' Passing to a strongly-typed view of type "ViewModel"
        Return View("serviceList",model:=vm)
    End Function

    ' This is where you post back, and data can be bound to type "ViewModel"
    <HttpPost()> _
    Function ServiceList(data As ViewModel) As ActionResult
        ' *Model Validation / Insert / Update*

        ' Refresh the page (if you want)
        RedirectToAction("ServiceList","Home")
    End Function
End Class
```

Razor View (serviceList.vbhtml):

```
@ModelType ViewModel
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            @For Each head In Model.TableHeaders
                @<th>@(head)</th>
            Next
        </tr>
        @For Each detail In Model.ServiceDetails
            @<tr id=@(detail.ServiceID)>
                 <td>@(detail.Name)</td>
                 <td>@(If(detail.YesSelected,"X",""))</td>
                 <td>@(If(detail.NoSelected,"X",""))</td>
                 <td>@(detail.LastDate)</td>
                 <td>@(detail.ProposedDate)</td>
             </tr>
        Next
    </table>
</div>
```

To post-back, you'll have to have javascript grab data entered into any input fields (I didn't include any here), and construct a JSON object--with the appropriate data--that reflects the argument in the Controller's post action.  I provided an example with an argument of type `ViewModel`.  This means your JSON fields have to match those defined in the `ViewModel` model, and their values have to match the respective property's data type.  ASP.NET will bind the data on post back.  Additionally `ViewModel` is complex, so you can post a list of `ViewRow` (for multiple record updates).  To bind this, your JSON object needs to have the `ServiceDetails` property that contains an array of objects that in turn have properties of `ServiceID`, `Name`, `YesSelected`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A collection of services in your viewmodel should do it, the Selected bool of course would represent the yes/no option and probably be bound to a checkbox.

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public IList<Service> Services {get;set;}
}

public class Service 
{
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
    public DateTime LastDate {get;set;}
    public DateTime ProposedDate {get;set;}
}
```